# Resizing image results in low resolution

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

So I am trying to use a specific PNG image for my map annotation. The original image is 761 x 761 and the resized annotation image that shows up in my app is all blurry and low-resolution-looking. Any idea why that is?

```
        chargerAnnotationImage = UIImage(named: "ChargerGreen")!
        let size = CGSize(width: 25, height: 25)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)
        chargerAnnotationImage.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height))
        let resizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return resizedImage
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

## Try this code for resize Image

The highest-level APIs for image resizing can be found in the UIKit framework. Given a UIImage, a temporary graphics context can be used to render a scaled version, using UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions() and UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext():

```
        let image = UIImage(named: "x-men")!
        let size = CGSizeApplyAffineTransform(image.size, CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.1, 0.1))
        let hasAlpha = false
        let scale: CGFloat = 0.0 // Automatically use scale factor of main screen
        
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, !hasAlpha, scale)
        image.drawInRect(CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: size))
        
        let scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return scaledImage
```

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions() creates a temporary rendering context into which the original is drawn. The first argument, size, is the target size of the scaled image. The second argument, isOpaque is used to determine whether an alpha channel is rendered. Setting this to false for images without transparency (i.e. an alpha channel) may result in an image with a pink hue. The third argument scale is the display scale factor. When set to 0.0, the scale factor of the main screen is used, which for Retina displays is 2.0 or higher (3.0 on the iPhone 6 Plus).